# Android fragment tab with viewpager for all api

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

i had dowload project from developer site
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

```
it rais error in 2.2 device i had attchage v4jar file yet it throws error

08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.effectivenavigation/com.example.android.effectivenavigation.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.effectivenavigation.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.effectivenavigation-1.apk]
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.effectivenavigation.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.effectivenavigation-1.apk]
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
08-27 05:20:35.352: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `ActionBarCompat` in order to have your Navigation Drawer working in devices below Honeycomb

You should import `v7 AppCompat` support library as a module to your project and change your `MainActivity` extending `ActionBarActivity`.

[developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

Comment: it will import actionbar but i want actionbar with fragment activity how can i extend both ?

Comment: I was exactly on the same problem: implementing Effective Navigation backward compatible on older devices. Change `FragmentActivity` to `ActionBarActivity` since it extends `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` and you have both in place.

Comment: If it resolved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted and let others with the same problem know the correct answer

Comment: it fine and working.. i had accept answer and up vote.Thankss

Answer (score 1):

Implement ActionBar in 2.2 device and other Functionlity like ViewPager,Framgmet Tag in 2.2 then there is two way using sherlockActionbar and AppCompat

Sherlock is and third party library while AppCompat is Android library.
step to use AppCompact in project
**just update android skd-> extra-> Android support library**
Then goto you sdk in your system-> Androidsdk\extras\android\support\v7 find appcompat source code. Import this appcompact in you eclipse.

Create you project and select appcompact library from property->android-> Library.

open you manifeast file and change theme `**android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light**"`
Then extend your activity with `ActionBarActivity` if you cannot found it then pls manualy import `

```
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;`
```

Then Add below code to activity

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```